# C# How to connect a TCPListener (server) behind a router

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, vpn

I have a client and server application in two computers. i am trying to connect them through internet TCP connection. the problem im facing is.

Client (192.168.1.2) -> [router] (124.43.224.112) --

-> (internet) -> [router] (124.43.190.63) -> Server (192.168.1.3)

How do i establish a TCP connection ?

Comment: You should not write anything special for that, you have to ask the IT guy to configure the network correctly so both computers can talk each other, using a VPN or configuring the ports or whatever your network infrastructure needs.

Answer (score 2):

Internet 101:

- Network Address Translation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation
- Port Forwarding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

The router 124.43.190.63 must be configured to do port forwarding to 192.168.1.3. Client connects to 124.43.190.63.

You must understand these basics if you're writing a networking application.

Comment: i dont understand anything! can u explain ?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the client to connect to a server that is hidden behind a router you need to setup port forwarding on the server's router. That way when the client attempts to connect to a configured port on the server's *router*, the request is forwarded onto the server.